# Faces distorted when rendered and 3D View in Rendermode does not work in Default Layout

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, faces, normals

I got two questions. First:

When rendered, these Faces/Vertices are messed up. I thought the normals were wrong, but it seems they aren't. The materials have no Texture and no alpha activated.
[image]

My second question is:
In the Default Layout (only there), my 3D View in Rendermode doesn't render, but shows the solid variant.

Comment: does the object have any modifier?

Comment: no, everything is applied. I only used a mirror modifier. I removed the faces one by on and added them again. No the Problem is solve for the front left and back right part. Btw. is use smooth shading. with flat there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt solve my second Problem, but this is only a minor one.

The answer to the First.

I had an Hemispheric Light in Blender Render. When i turned this off there was no problem anymore. I am Using this figure for Unity, an there was no Problem at all.